# How to add customer email to address templates in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add customer email to invoice and shipment pdfs. A good solution would be to add it to address template. But I couldn't find the right variable. What is the easiest way to accomplish this.

Something like this not working example would be perfect.

```
 {{depend email}}Email: {{var email}}{{/depend}}
```

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 with Firegento Pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For Guest

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
```

and for member

```
{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

tested in magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code into your custom email template:
Email: {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}